# zmv to rename Unicode characters (e.g. u0308 'COMBINING DIAERESIS') on Mac/zsh-shell

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, unicode, filenames

While cleaning a file server I found unwanted or non-ASCII characters in many filenames.
To rename unwanted filenames, I normally use the comfortable zmv command in a zsh shell on an OSX machine.

To find unwanted characters I use: `LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[! -~]*'`

My find result outputs many Unicode characters 'COMBINING DIAERESIS' (U+0308) "ü" in my filenames. (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm).
I am using zsh on OSX in an x-term 256, text encoding: Unicode UTF-8. My locale settings/ LC_CTYPE="en_DE.UTF-8")

`echo -e 'u\u0308'` outputs ü correctly.
`find . -name '*u<0308>*'` (works as expected - please note "<0308>" in the previous find command was actually an ü which was substituted during the cut&paste process into the zsh window)

How can I replace Unicode characters in filenames (e.g. u0308) using zmv?
This is what I am trying so far:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)(#qD.)' '$f:gs/u[$(0308)]/ue'
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like cutting and pasting the multi-byte characters into the command line will work:

```shell
> zmv -n '**/*(#qD.)' '$f:gs/ü/ue'
mv -- f1/abcü123 f1/abcue123
mv -- f2/MüüMüM f2/MueueMueM

> zmv -n '**/*ü*(#qD.)' '${f//ü/ue}'
mv -- f1/abcü123 f1/abcue123
mv -- f2/MüüMüM f2/MueueMueM
```

There are some contexts where you can use explicit character encodings, e.g. in substitutions:

```shell
> f=Au$'\u308'B
> print $f
AüB
> print ${f//u$'\u308'/ue}
AueB
```

But this doesn't appear to work with `zmv`, possibly because of the parsing of the input patterns by the `zmv` function.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for since the zmv command (with a normalized unicode inside): `zmv -n '(**/)(*)(#qD.)' '$f:gs/ä/ae'` replaces not only combined unicodes `print 'a\u308'` ==> ä but also normalized unicodes `print 'ä'` ==> ä which I actually did not want to replace.
But it seems to be a good (the only?) approach...
_I was hoping to get a solution with which I can address the character I want directly in zmv, for example via its HEX code._